# Side Scrolling Issue

Tags: css, highslide

I am having a hard time seeing where this overscroll is coming from, can anyone point me in the right direction?

http://www.turbokits.com/Ford/Mustang/Turbo_Kits/Hellion_Power_Systems_Eliminator_Twin_Turbo_Kit/1659/

I thought it was the highslide- classes doing it, but apparently adding in the `overflow-x:hidden` does not make a difference...

Comment: Website you provide is not working for me

Comment: comes up for me on 3 different machines in 3 different locations in the US... dns was just updated last night so maybe not fully propogated yet...  urrrggggg

Comment: It appears to be caused by your #pageContent element. If you hide it, the scroll disappears. I hid the header and footer as well and nothing changed, so I arrived at that conclusion. As for the what's actually happening, I don't know. Hopefully others can find out knowing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the following div and remove it:

```
section#pagecontent article #contentWrapper #innerContent #SiteContent_PartDetails .part form #part li section#image .clear
```

Just to summarize, it's the `<div class="clear"></div>` inside `<section id="image">`.

Answer (score 0):

one simple solution is to add style `overflow-x:hidden;` to body tag.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is an answer and will resolve the issue what o7th Web Design is facing